# Bat script works in Jenkins freestyle job, but doesn't work in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robocopy

I have a bat script that executes some Robocopy commands. This bat script is working fine in the Jenkins freestyle job but does not work in the Jenkins pipeline. The script finishes with exit code 2.

This is my bat script. (%source% and %destination% values are set)

```sh
@echo off
ROBOCOPY %source% %destination% /is /it /E
@echo robocopy exit code: %ERRORLEVEL%
@if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 3 ( echo robocopy ERROR )
@if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 3 ( exit %ERRORLEVEL% )
@set ERRORLEVEL=0

echo =======================================================
echo  Moving database runtime Completed
echo =======================================================
```

This is the console out of the build.

```
09:31:38  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09:31:38  
09:31:38                 Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
09:31:38      Dirs :         6         0         6         0         0       470
09:31:38     Files :         4         0         4         0         0      1588
09:31:38     Bytes :   786.0 k         0   786.0 k         0         0   13.08 m
09:31:38     Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
09:31:38     Ended : Tuesday, December 14, 2021 05:01:38
09:31:38  
09:31:38  robocopy exit code: 0
09:31:38  =======================================================
09:31:38   Moving database runtime Completed
09:31:38  =======================================================
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
```

The same script works fine when it runs as a freestyle job. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Could you, please, paste your pipeline code?

Comment: Try to add `exit /b 0` for success case.